# Why does html tags (s, strong) not work in jasper reports?

Tags: html, jasper-reports

I'm add in static text html tag but after click on preview bold and strikethrough not show correctly.

Also when load data from database it is not show correctly.

[image: Example]

Any solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jasper Report does not support all html tags, the support tags are defined in [Styled Text Sample](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/styledtext/index.html)

As you can see `<s>` and `<strong>` tag are not supported.

Your choice is to replace them with `<font style="text-decoration: line-through">` and `<b>` if you like to use html

or

`<style isStrikeThrough="true">` and `<style isBold="true">` and then use styled text instead of html.

If you have dynamic data you can use java to replace it

```
${myField}.replace("<s>","<font style=\"text-decoration: line-through\">").
        replace("</s>","</font>").
        replace("<strong>","<b>").replace("</strong>","</b>")
```

*If you need to replace multiple tags, I would recommend creating a method in java (static) and call this method instead of executing the replace within the report*

### Example

**jrxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="html" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="fe5b2242-b491-46ba-8456-aa71ae5e2212">
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <title>
        <band height="53" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="210" height="50" uuid="e462bb03-e884-4b5b-b41f-2867a4bd63b2"/>
                <textElement markup="html"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["<s>&lt;s&gt;</s> and <strong>&lt;strong&gt;</strong> will not work but <font style=\"text-decoration: line-through\">&lt;font style=\"text-decoration: line-through\"&gt;</font> and <b>&lt;b&gt;</b> will"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="220" y="0" width="220" height="50" uuid="744bb631-d03a-452e-ae5e-19e7ef5a378a"/>
                <textElement markup="html"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["With java however you can replace'em and both <s>&lt;s&gt;</s> and <strong>&lt;strong&gt;</strong> will work".replace("<s>","<font style=\"text-decoration: line-through\">").replace("</s>","</font>").replace("<strong>","<b>").replace("</strong>","</b>")]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

**Result**

[image: result]

Comment: Tnx for help, but is it possible replace  <s>TEXT</s> I need get TEXT isStrikeThrough

Comment: @Pointer sorry I missed that you needed strike-through also, I have updated answer adding that, the principal is the same.

Answer (score 0):

In case you face the situation that bold fonts work in preview, but not in the resulting PDF, add this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
    <version>6.19.1</version>
</dependency>
```